# Why does Create React App hosted on ZEIT Now not show a 404 response?

Tags: create-react-app, vercel

If I try `mywebsite.com/NON-EXISTENT-PATH` for my site on Google App Engine, I get a 404 response.

However using create-react-app's local development server for another app, if I try `localhost:3000/NON-EXISTENT-PATH`, it just gives me the response for `localhost:3000`, rather than a 404. This also applies to hosting the app on ZEIT Now. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create React App is auto-detected and a wildcard route is added so that any path that doesn’t match a static file will serve `/index.html`.

https://zeit.co/docs/v2/build-step#optimized-frameworks

This is necessary for frameworks that don't create HTML files for each page but instead create a single index.html file and use JavaScript to route on the frontend.

This pattern is typically called [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: If I fetch() a JSON file and it's missing, I want it to fail with a 404 rather than `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. Is this just a downside of SPAs?

Comment: Yes it’s a downside. You might want to try a static site generator (SSG) instead like Next.js

Comment: Thanks. Re. your answer, edit it to reflect that only not found paths hit the wildcard route?